# Update multiple objects from array of object in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection similar to the following schema:

```
{
  "id": "1234657980", 
  "company": "samsung",
  "models": [
    {
      "name": "A1",
      "processor": "P1",
      "price": 10000
    },
    {
      "name": "A2",
      "processor": "P2",
      "price": 20000
    },
    {
      "name": "A3",
      "processor": "P3",
      "price": 30000
    }
  ]
}
```

I am running the node js app and using the mongoose. I want to update the above collection to update the models array with the following data:

```
{
  "name": "A1",
  "processor": "new P1",
  "price": 15000
}
{
  "name": "A2",
  "processor": "new P2",
  "price": 25000
}
```

Basically, here I want to replace data for A1 and A2, and along with that, I want to push the new data into the array like

```
{
  "name": "A4",
  "processor": "P4",
  "price": 40000
}
```

I want to update the values of A1 and A2 and, at the same time, add A4 to the same array in a single DB call.
I don't want to replace the whole array in place because the real data is security sensitive, and I can't replace the whole object because it will create issues if, while I am replacing the data for one request and at the same time another request comes to update the data, it will replace the whole object and I might lose the data in between.
The data is so sensitive that I can't use the real property name and structure, but I created the minimal required structure of the collection for debugging purposes.
Also, there are some constraints when using the bulkWrite() function of mongoose.
Using simple if else conditions will not work as it is not fixed that I will always get requests to update A1 and A2 at a time, but it will be a single object or even more than 3-4 objects at the same time along with that sometime it will have the new data to be pushed and some time not.

I tried using multiple $set with if else conditions, but my data is dynamic, and I do not have control over how many objects I will get for an update. I also tried using $push with $set in a single updateMany() function, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the order,

one option is to use an update with pipeline, `$reducing` the `models` array and checking each item compared to the `newArr`:

```
db.collection.update(
  {id: "1234657980"},
  [{$set: {models: {$let: {
          vars: {newArr: newArr},
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              {$reduce: {
                  input: "$models",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {$concatArrays: [
                      "$$value",
                      [
                        {$cond: [
                            {$in: ["$$this.name", "$$newArr.name"]},
                            {$first: {$filter: {
                                  input: "$$newArr",
                                  as: "newItem",
                                  cond: {$eq: ["$$this.name", "$$newItem.name"]}
                            }}},
                            "$$this"
                        ]}
                      ]
                  ]}
              }},
              {$filter: {
                  input: "$$newArr",
                  cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$this.name", "$models.name"]}}
              }}
          ]}
  }}}}]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zph_hANo7VV)

Otherwise, if the order of items do not matter, there are simpler options, like, simply `concatArrays` of `newArr` and `$filtered` `models`:

```
db.collection.update(
  {id: "1234657980"},
  [{$set: {models: {$let: {
          vars: {newArr: newArr},
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              {$filter: {
                  input: "$models",
                  cond: {$not: {$in: ["$$this.name", "$$newArr.name"]}}
              }},
              "$$newArr"
          ]}
  }}}}]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rTeJAI0ghfP)

Comment: Thank you @nimrod-serok
This worked and helped a lot.